# cplex: define custom mathematical function

Tags: cplex, opl, custom-function

I want to define a custom function *f* in the implementation of my optimisation model in cplex, but some mathematical functions are not available. I want to use my customised function *f* to make a relation between two of my model variables decisions. Here in how is defined *f(x)* (it is the CDF of normal distribution):

Thank you for any detail!

[image: cutom function]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to do so directly. CPLEX will only allow linear and a small subset of non-linear relations such as quadratic or second-order cone functions. You may be able to approximate your function with a piecewise linear function.

Comment: As you said, it is not really possible to do it. I have used a python script to solve my problem. Thank you!